# How to pass a share value to Processes which has jit / njit function that read and modify the share value?

Tags: python-3.x, numba, jit

I am trying to have an integer value which would be assigned to a multiprocess programme and each process has a jit funtion to read and modify the value.

I came accross with multiprocessing.Manager().value which would pass a share value to each process, but numba.jit does not accept this type.

Is there any solution to work around it?

```
import numba
import multiprocessing

@numba.jit()
def jj (o, ii):
    print (o.value)
    o.value = ii
    print (o.value)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    o = multiprocessing.Manager().Value('i',  0 , lock=False)
    
    y1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=jj, args=(o,10))
    y1.daemon = True
    
    y2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=jj, args=(o,20))
    y2.daemon = True

    y1.start()
    y2.start()
    
    y1.join()
    y2.join()
```

Comment: Please make the post more clear and detailed starting from the first sentence ("I am trying to an integer" which does not mean anything to me). Please also add a code snippet so to explain what you tried and read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . I did not find `multiprocess.manager()`, did you mean `multiprocessing.Manager()`? If so please note that Multiprocessing cannot be used in Numba njitted functions and clearly not managers (because of the typing system). The standard way to parallelize a Numba code is to use its internal multithreading functions (see the Numba doc).

Comment: Hi, I have corrected it. Hope it is clearer.

Comment: If I have to keep multiprocessing rather than threading, how could I do as just simply to pass a share value and can be modified and other process can read the modication?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify a CPython object from an njit function so the function will (almost) not benefit from Numba (the only optimization Numba can do is looplifting but it cannot be used here anyway). What you try to archive is not possible with multiprocessing + njitted Numba functions. Numba can be fast because it does not operate on CPython types but native ones but multiprocessing's managers operate on only on CPython types. You can use the very experimental objmode scope of Numba so to execute pure-Python in a Numba function but be aware that this is slow (and it sometimes just crash currently).

Another big issue is that shared CPython objects are protected by the global interpreter lock (GIL) which basically prevent any parallel speed-up inside a process (unless on IO-based codes or similar things). The GIL is designed so to protect the interpreter of *race conditions* on the internal state of objects. AFAIK, managers can transfer pure-Python objects between processes thanks to pickling (which is slow), but using `lock=False` is unsafe and can also cause a race condition (not at the interpreter level thanks to the GIL).

Note the Numba function have to be recompiled for each process which is slow (caching can help the subsequent runs but not the first time because of concurrent compilation in multiple processes).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, in the real design I have here, speed is much more important that is reason why using lock = False by purpose.

I am also trying to resolve the recompiling numba function for each process because it is really slow at the beginning. Am I right that njit would take much more time than jit in compiling?

Comment: Correctness matters more than performance. This is why you should be sure about the lock=false. Race conditions are very complex to debug and running the program does not help to know if there are any (only proofs can). Note that transmitting objects between CPython processes is slow and I do not expect the lock to be a huge problem (locks are cheap unless they are already locked but if they need to be so, then it means removing it would have certainly caused a race condition, so a bogus program).

Comment: As for the cost of the recompilation, caching solve this as said in the answer (more specifically the `cache=True` flag). For `njit`, Numba try to compile the function in all cases so using jit instead of njit is not faster. The former cause a slow fallback pure-Python code to be called while the second just throw an error. If you really care about performance, the second is generally what you want (at the expense of a less robust code). For more information, please read the Numba doc about njit.

Comment: I am not sure why my design got much shorter time for first time running on jit rather than njit. njitted function should be faster than jit, I have done some testing on some simple functions which proves it right. but something happened to my design here the entire running time for the programme inc the complie time, jit version is better as too much time on the first time running.